# Lowest Common Ancestor recursively in Java

Tags: java

I've found a solution to the lowest common ancestor problem in java in leetcode. The problem stated otherwise is, find the lowest common ancestor of p and q with the BST rooted at root.
Here's my code.

```
public TreeNode lowestCommonAncestor(TreeNode root, TreeNode p, TreeNode q) {
        if(root == null || root == p || root == q) return root;
        TreeNode left = lowestCommonAncestor(root.left, p, q);
        TreeNode right = lowestCommonAncestor(root.right, p, q);
        return left != null && right != null ? root : left == null?right :left;

    }
```

While this works for most cases, if the tree is something like this and the question is lowestCommonAncestor(1, 2, 3) or lowest common ancestor of 2 and 3 where root == 1;

```
1 -> 2 -> 3
```

Then to my mind the answer this solution will provide is `2`, 
This is because after the recursion

```
left = null
right = 2
```

while the actual answer is 1.

However this solution works. Can someone help me understand what am I getting wrong here.

Comment: What are `p` and `q` in this scenario?

Comment: No I mean in the latter part, you've provided the tree structure but not the other two input parameters to the method, so it's hard to discuss what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the logic:

```
lowestCommonAncestor(root=1, p=2, q=3):
    if (root == null || root == p || root == q) return root;
    //     false           false        false

    left = lowestCommonAncestor(2, 2, 3):
               if (root == null || root == p || root == q) return root
               //     false            true                return 2

    right = lowestCommonAncestor(null, 2, 3):
                if (root == null || root == p || root == q) return root;
                //      true                                return null

    return left != null && right != null ? root : left == null ? right : left;
    //         true        false                     false             : 2
```

Result: `2`

Easiest way to follow the code is to use a **debugger**.

Answer (score 1):

After execution of `TreeNode right = lowestCommonAncestor(root.right, p, q);`,

you get:

```
left=null;
right=2;
```

At last, the result=`(left!=null && right!=null)?root:(left==null?right:left)`;

Return result:`2`